# How to get Unique Modulus Operator for Alphanumeric string

Tags: java, module, mapreduce, hashcode, hadoop2

I have written mapreduce application that read records from HBase and write into text files in .
I have used custom partitioner class when i have written so many if else based on that i write into 2k text files .

The problem is that i have 2k if else condition like this.

```
if (str.contains("Japan|^|BUS")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|CAS")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|CUS")) {
            return 2;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|FTN")) {
            return 3;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|GEO")) {
            return 4;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|INC")) {
            return 5;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|OPM")) {
            return 6;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|PEN")) {
            return 7;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|SHE")) {
            return 8;
        }
```

And it continues till 2000.

I have tried Hashcode but collision occurs and i am not able to separate my key value properly .

```
return ((Math.abs(strPartitionKey.hashCode())) % setNumRedTask);
```

I also have tried hashmap cache using global HashMap but this does not work for all mapper because for each mapper HashMap reinitialized .

If i get unique number then also using % operation result in collision.

Please help .

Comment: If I correctly understand,you need to generate unique numbers.Can you try generating random integer number with a seed specified so that it will generate same number whenever the alphanumeric string is encountered.( Using Linear Congruential generator, so collision chances would be very very less ).

Comment: @DeepanRam yes i will try that also but there i have to make sure there should not be any collision otherwise data finding will be very huge .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator 
Chances of collision is less if the parameters are choosen wisely. Samples  are shared in the wiki page.